# Get a .tmx file from its .json

Tags: json, phaser-framework, tiled, tmx

I've been using Tiled to create .tmx maps for one of my projects, maps that I export to JSON before using with Phaser.js.

Problem is, a few months ago I mistakenly deleted the .tmx file for the game first map. It's still working fine but now I can't change anything on the first map layout with Tiled because I only have the JSON for it.

I've been looking for an answer with no success so far, but is there a way to convert a .json Tiled map exported from a .tmx file, back to its original format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply open the JSON exported map in Tiled, and save it again as a TMX file. To be able to select the file, you may need to change the file type in the Open File dialog.

Btw, you should consider committing your project to a version control system ([Git](https://git-scm.com/) is a popular one), so that such mistakes will not generally lead to loss of data. You don't always get lucky.

Comment: Omg the option to change the file type in the Open File dialog was hidden by default on my pc and I totally forgot about it, I'm an idiot ahahah. Thanks man, and yep this happened like a year ago, I started using Git a few months ago and I'm using it almost daily now :)